# Mongo DB get average on sub field of collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given the following item in a collection, how would I get the average of assessment.answer field where id == 1 for all records? Also I need to return the first index of subs[] with each record like subs[0]

```
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("57b5e55e8426706357a90728"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-08-20T00:21:16.497Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-08-18T16:42:06.173Z"),
    "password" : "password",
    "email" : "test@user.com",
    "lastName" : "User",
    "firstName" : "Test",
    "assessment" : [ 
        {
            "subs" : [ 
                100, 
                100, 
                100, 
                100, 
                100
            ],
            "answer" : 2,
            "id" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "subs" : [ 
                80, 
                40, 
                100, 
                60, 
                20
            ],
            "answer" : 2,
            "id" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "subs" : [ 
                80, 
                20, 
                20, 
                20, 
                20
            ],
            "answer" : 4,
            "id" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "subs" : [ 
                80, 
                100, 
                60, 
                100, 
                100
            ],
            "answer" : 5,
            "id" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "subs" : [ 
                60, 
                100, 
                100, 
                100, 
                100
            ],
            "answer" : 1,
            "id" : 5
        }, 
        {
            "subs" : [ 
                100, 
                100, 
                100, 
                100, 
                100
            ],
            "answer" : 3,
            "id" : 6
        }, 
        {
            "subs" : [ 
                80, 
                20, 
                100, 
                80, 
                60
            ],
            "answer" : 3,
            "id" : 7
        }, 
        {
            "subs" : [ 
                20, 
                20, 
                20, 
                20, 
                20
            ],
            "answer" : 4,
            "id" : 8
        }, 
        {
            "subs" : [ 
                60, 
                60, 
                60, 
                60, 
                40
            ],
            "answer" : 5,
            "id" : 9
        }, 
        {
            "subs" : [ 
                60, 
                60, 
                60, 
                60, 
                40
            ],
            "answer" : 3,
            "id" : 10
        }, 
        {
            "subs" : [ 
                100, 
                100, 
                100, 
                100, 
                100
            ],
            "answer" : 4,
            "id" : 11
        }, 
        {
            "subs" : [ 
                80, 
                80, 
                80, 
                80, 
                80
            ],
            "answer" : 1,
            "id" : 12
        }, 
        {
            "subs" : [ 
                60, 
                60, 
                60, 
                60, 
                60
            ],
            "answer" : 2,
            "id" : 13
        }, 
        {
            "subs" : [ 
                40, 
                40, 
                40, 
                40, 
                40
            ],
            "answer" : 3,
            "id" : 14
        }, 
        {
            "subs" : [ 
                80, 
                20, 
                20, 
                20, 
                100
            ],
            "answer" : 3,
            "id" : 15
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 51
}
```

Comment: What is your MongoDB server version?

Comment: The version is 3.0.7

Comment: Please see updated question...

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You need to select only the documents that match your condition with [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) and [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

```
var ids = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
var matchStage = { "$match": { "assessment.id": { "$in": ids } } };

db.accounts.aggregate(
    [
        matchStage,
        { "$unwind": "$assessment" }, 
        matchStage,
        { "$group": { 
            "_id": null, 
            "avg": { "$avg": "$assessment.answer" }
        }} 
    ]
)
```

Starting from MongoDB 3.2, you can do it like this:

```
db.accounts.aggregate(
    [
        matchStage,
        { "$project": { 
            "preAvg": { 
                "$avg": { 
                    "$map": { 
                        "input": { 
                            "$filter": { 
                                "input": "$assessment", 
                                "as": "el", 
                                "cond": { "$setIsSubset": [ [ "$$el.id" ], ids ] }
                            }  
                        }, 
                        "as": "val", 
                        "in": "$$val.answer" 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        }}, 
        { "$group": {  
            "_id": null, 
            "avg": { "$sum": "$preAvg" } 
        }}
    ]
)
```

Comment: For Example, I want to see all where assessment is is 1. Then for each of those records se an average of each index in the subs array. so if 2 people have answer id = 1, show and average of subs[0] for those users. If each picked 1 and 4 respectively, I should see 2